# How to save my sent ping packets in omnetpp?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I need to save all the sent ping packets in a .pcap format to work on it latter but when I try to save them there is no packet in the file and its empty. I would be thankful if someone could tell me which part I'm doing wrong.here is the code I'm using to capture ping packets.

```
**.crcMode = "computed"               
**.fcsMode = "computed"           
**.numPcapRecorders = 1                          
**.pcapRecorder[1].pcapLinkType = 105    
**.pcapRecorder[1].pcapFile = "results/all2.pcap" 
**.pcapRecorder[1].verbose = true            
**.pcapRecorder[1].alwaysFlush = true              
**.pcapRecorder[1].packetFilter = "ping* or Ping*"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Bests,

Comment: What INET version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Instant veins5.2-i2, Inetv4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

The array indexing starts at 0. So if there is only one PCAP recorder per module, it is pcapRecorder[0].

Comment: actually there are two and the other one just works fine but I cant capture ping packets.

Comment: According to your configuration `**.numPcapRecorders = 1`, there is a **single** PCAP recorder configured, so @adamgeorge309 is correct that using index 1 does NOT match anything in your network.

Comment: you are right, I'm sorry It was a typo here, in my code it is ok as you said, but seems there is something wrong with my filter.

Comment: Does it work if you use * as the filter?

Comment: Also, is the link layer header type set correctly? It's currently set to 802.11, which might be correct depending on where you are capturing packets.

Comment: yes it works with ARP packets and * but not ping. about the second question I dont understand you, but I'm using PingApp to send pings.

Comment: Regarding the second question, apparently, the link-layer header type is no longer a parameter of the PCAP recorder module (it figures it out automatically now). So the question is irrelevant.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to Omnet++ and I didn't get you, would you please tell me if there is any way to do so? I need to know how many packets and from which source to what destination in what time is sent? so using PingApp I should do something else?

Comment: It works for me in INET 4.3

Comment: would you please tell me the filter you are using?

Comment: I used the same filter you used in the code above, ping* or Ping*